# Google Line Charts. Remove extra gridlines or change their color

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I've created google line chart with the following settings:

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawCharts);
function drawCharts() {
    var options = {
        backgroundColor:{fill:'transparent'},
        legend:'none',
        series:{0:{color:'#aa8e57'}},
        lineWidth:4,
        pointSize:7,
        chartArea:{width: '86%'},    
        hAxis:{
            textStyle:{color:'#ffffff',fontSize:12},
            gridlines:{color:'#2a261d'},
            baselineColor:'#b19c72' 
        },
        vAxis:{
            textStyle:{color:'#ffffff',fontSize:12},
            gridlines:{color:'#2a261d'},
            baselineColor:'#b19c72'
        },
    };

    var dataMembers = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataMembers.addColumn('string', 'Date');
    dataMembers.addColumn('number', 'Users');
    dataMembers.addRows([
        ['13.11.2018',5], ['14.11.2018',7], ['15.11.2018',10]
    ]);    
    var membersChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('membersChart'));
    membersChart.draw(dataMembers, options);
}
```

I read all docs and cant find out how to customize those white extra lines:
[image]

I've done a lot of experiments, but i can't find out how they appears and how to remove them from the chart. Or at least, change their color to match rest of gridlines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

those are --> `minorGridlines`

for the same color...

```
minorGridlines:{color:'#2a261d'},
```

to remove...

```
minorGridlines:{count:0},
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawCharts);
function drawCharts() {
    var options = {
        backgroundColor:{fill:'transparent'},
        legend:'none',
        series:{0:{color:'#aa8e57'}},
        lineWidth:4,
        pointSize:7,
        chartArea:{width: '86%'},    
        hAxis:{
            textStyle:{color:'#ffffff',fontSize:12},
            gridlines:{color:'#2a261d'},
            minorGridlines:{color:'#2a261d'},
            baselineColor:'#b19c72' 
        },
        vAxis:{
            textStyle:{color:'#ffffff',fontSize:12},
            gridlines:{color:'#2a261d'},
            minorGridlines:{color:'#2a261d'},
            baselineColor:'#b19c72'
        },
    };

    var dataMembers = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataMembers.addColumn('string', 'Date');
    dataMembers.addColumn('number', 'Users');
    dataMembers.addRows([
        ['13.11.2018',5], ['14.11.2018',7], ['15.11.2018',10]
    ]);    
    var membersChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('membersChart'));
    membersChart.draw(dataMembers, options);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
}

#membersChart {
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="membersChart"></div>
```

Comment: It works, thanks! Can you also explain why the vertical lines doesn't shows up ? If i change column type from "string" to "date" -  they are visible then.

Comment: that's the reason, they appear for a continuous axis (date, number, etc.) and not for a discrete axis (string) -- see [discrete vs continuous](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#discrete-vs-continuous)